# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not called on ios10

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, ios10, devicetoken

I have 2 iphones: 1 - with ios 10 and 2 - with ios 9

**While trying the 1st iphone:**

`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method is not called when user clicks "allow" on the alert
Though, the method `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` IS called. 
In this case device does NOT receive push notifications.

**While trying the 2nd iphone:**

Both methods are called here. And device DOES receive push notifications.

**Then I checked on simulator ios 8**

In this case the same as in 1st. Only one method is called.

I checked some answers for similar question but they didn't help me. 
I doubt that the issue is somewhere within push notifications settings, cuz ios 9 works OK. 
So the issue is somewhere within ios 10.

**The very questions are:**

1. How can I call method `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`
2. Or how can I get the device token since it's the goal

Looking forward for your help!

Comment: How did you register for notifications? Did you register using both `-registerUserNotificationSettings:` and `-registerForRemoteNotifications` from `UIApplication`? The latter one is needed for `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` to be called. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623078-registerforremotenotifications.

Comment: may be you can get help from here. https://www.sitepoint.com/developing-push-notifications-for-ios-10/

Comment: You can follow the above steps to get work push notifications in ios 10
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572897/ios-10-push-notification-issue-solved

Answer (score 10):

For iOS 10 using xCode 8 GM.

This issue solved with the following steps. 
Requirements :- Xcode 8 GM Seed.
MAC OS :- Captain EL 10.11.6

Do not remove your code for IOS 9 or below versions.

**Step 1:-**
Go To --> Target Settings in Xcode --> Capabilities --> Enable PushNotifications.

**Step 2:-**
Add UserNotifications framework --> Build Phase --> Link Libraries

**Step 3:-**

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder   <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@end
```

**Step 4:-** 
In the method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions register for UIUserNotificationSettings.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUALTO(@"10.0")){
        UNUserNotificationCenter *notifiCenter = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        notifiCenter.delegate = self;
        [notifiCenter requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
             if( !error ){
                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
             }
         }];  
    }

    return YES;
    }
```

**Step 5:-** Implement the 2 delegate methods of UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate.

```
    -(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{

//Do Your Code.................Enjoy!!!!
    }

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the Project Settings. Select your project. Go to Second tab -> Capabilities -> Select Push Notification to ON.

Answer (score 0):

You should call this method inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
func registerForNotifications(){
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            center.requestAuthorization(options:[.alert,.sound,.badge]) { (granted, error) in
                if granted{
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }else{
                    print("Notification permission denied.")
                    if !(SharedPrefs.sharedInstance!.isLoggedIn){
                        Defaults.sharedPref.removeNotificationToken()
                    }else{
                        UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
                        print("We will delete the token at the time of logout")
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            // For ios 9 and below
            let type: UIUserNotificationType = [.alert,.sound,.badge];
            let setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: type, categories: nil);
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(setting);
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
```